# How can I left-justify Text objects inside of a DisclosureGroup?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showItems = false
    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup("Show items", isExpanded: $showItems){
            ForEach(0 ..< 10){i in
                Text("\(i)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am unsure of how to have the `Text`s centered once the DisclosureGroup is expanded. I have tried the `.frame(alignment: .leading)` view modifier as well as wrapping the Group in a `VStack(alignment: .leading)`, both to no effect. How do I get the text left-justified? I am using Xcode 12.4 with Swift 5.3.2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the frame a `maxWidth` as well so that it'll expand. Otherwise (as you can see from my red debugging border), it'll only be as wide as the `Text` elements.

```
DisclosureGroup("Show items", isExpanded: $showItems){
            VStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< 10){i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .border(Color.red)
        }
```

Comment: For me, the `frame` gives a build time warning "Invalid frame dimension (negative or non-finite).", and then crashes with the error Invalid parameter not satisfying: <SwiftUI.SwiftUIWindow: 0x14de28630>. "frame=CGRectContainsRect(CGRectMake((CGFloat)INT_MIN, (CGFloat)INT_MIN, (CGFloat)INT_MAX - (CGFloat)INT_MIN, (CGFloat)INT_MAX - (CGFloat)INT_MIN), frame)" (running on Mac 12.4).